# get file size before downloading using HTTP header not matching with one retrieved from urlopen

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

why is the content-lenght different in case of using `requests` and `urlopen(url).info()`

```
>>> url = 'http://pymotw.com/2/urllib/index.html'

>>> requests.head(url).headers.get('content-length', None)
'8176'
>>> urllib.urlopen(url).info()['content-length']
'38227'
>>> len(requests.get(url).content)
38274
```

I was going to make a check for size of file in bytes to split the buffer to multiple threads based on `Range` in `urllib2`  but if I do not have the actual size of file in bytes it won't work..

only `len(requests.get(url).content)` gives `38274` which is closest but still not correct and moreover it is downloading the content which i didn't wanted.

Comment: It might be that the server does not correctly support `HEAD`. Or it might be that the server returns different things based on other headers sent (or not) by the respective methods (user-agent, cookies...). Try using `curl -v url` and `curl -I`, or any other method that sends the exact same request save for the `HEAD` instead of post, and check the results.

Comment: Maybe first size is the compressed size?

Comment: @BlackBear : then how to get uncompressed size ?

Comment: You can have a (very rough) estimate by looking at the compression method. For example, gzip has a compression ratio of 3:1 - 5:1 (source: http://superuser.com/questions/139253/what-is-the-maximum-compression-ratio-of-gzip#answer-139273)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default, requests will send `'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'` as part of the request headers, and the server will respond with the compressed content:

```
>>> r = requests.head('http://pymotw.com/2/urllib/index.html')
r>>> r.headers['content-encoding'], r.headers['content-length']
('gzip', '8201')
```

But, if you manually set the request headers, then you'll get the uncompressed content:

```
>>> r = requests.head('http://pymotw.com/2/urllib/index.html',headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'})
>>> r.headers['content-length']
'38227'
```